# How to use *ngFor in ngb-tabset?

Tags: angular, typescript

How to create tabs dynamically in `ngb-tabset`

Component code

```
 tabs = ['Tab-1','Tab-2'];
```

HTML Code

```
<ngb-tabset #tabs>
  <ngb-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs" [title]="tab">
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
       Some Data
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
</ngb-tabset>
```

I'm getting an error

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
    at NgForOf.webpackJsonp.../../../common/@angular/common.es5.js.NgForOf.ngOnChanges (common.es5.js:1689)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.es5.js:10812)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.es5.js:12238)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:12177)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:12880)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.es5.js:12821)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (TabsMatchesComponent.html:14)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.es5.js:12806)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12144)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12507)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What it is happening here is that you are using the same name for the element  where you are creating a local var named tabs. This is what the *ngFor is trying to iterate and not your component variable named tabs.

I suggest you change any of the names to a different one and try again.